# socketio stop and wait for next action in python

Tags: python, socket.io

Is there a way to stop execution and wait for input again on a socketio submittion?

For instance with the following code,  on submit, the method self.check_input() validates information.  If this were to show up with invalid data, I want to stop the chain of execution and keep the socket open to wait for the next 'on_submit'.  currently it just keeps on rolling along with exceptions because the data was invalid...

How can this be accomplished?

```
from socketio.namespace import BaseNamespace

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config.from_object(settings)

@app.route('/socket.io/<path:remaining>')
def iocg(remaining):
    socketio_manage(request.environ, {'/testclass': TestClass}, request)
    return 'done'


class TestClass(BaseNamespace):
    def on_submit(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.check_input()
        self.r_server = Redis('localhost')
        self.cgc = coregrapherconf
        self.scg = supportcoregrapher
        self.run_stuff()
```

Answer (score 1):

The socket is kept open, until you close it from the client side. You have to send some status message back, so that the browser knows, that something goes wrong:

```
class TestClass(BaseNamespace):
    def on_submit(self, data):
        self.data = data
        if not self.check_input():
            return "invalid data"
        self.r_server = Redis('localhost')
        self.cgc = coregrapherconf
        self.scg = supportcoregrapher
        self.run_stuff()
        return "everything's ok"
```